# Best way to implement partial key hashing

Tags: algorithm

I appeared for an interview where I was asked to write an algorithm for partial key hashing i.e; if ABCBC is inserted in the hash then searching for any of the sub strings should return the value stored. 
My answer was to create a collection of all possible substrings of a given key and maintain a mapping between each substring to its one or more parent string. Then maintain a BST of the collection of all substrings. Each node will point to a collection of actual values which that substring might match to. 
For eg. 
A, AB, ABC, ABCB, ABCBC, B, BC, BCB, BCBC, C, CB, CBC are possible substrings for this string. There may be other strings also like BAB of which, AB and B are substring of. 
So given AB, it will map to two strings BAB and ABCBC.

Is there any other more efficient way ? 
Thanks

Comment: You could store the substring nodes in a hashtable (hashing on the substring value, obviously). This would cut your search from O(log n) to O(1). Space complexity would be comparable or slightly worse (due to empty slots in the table).

Comment: It seems like creating a hash for each substring can become unfeasible... perhaps there is a different trick going on here? Anything usable with prefix trees?

Comment: Suffix tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) perhaps, although it's not really "hashing". I don't really understand how the overall collection works: suppose I insert ABCBC with a value of 4. Then searching for ABC returns 4, fair enough. What if I also insert CDABC with a value of 5. Now what does searching for ABC return? You can't say "should return the value stored" and also say, "it will map to two strings", because it can't do both.

Comment: A substring can appear in the middle of a string, so you may have both a suffix and a prefix to add.

Comment: My link should have been to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree

Comment: @Steve: You are right, it will give both the values just like a multimap.

Answer (score 3):

Store each substring in the hash, with a note for whether it is final, and the possible next characters and previous characters.  Store previous characters for all words that could have this substring in the middle, and next characters for all words that have this substring as their start.

Thus the entry for `a` does not need to have all words with `a` in it.  But it is easy enough to build that list if you want to.  Also during an insert as soon as you are going down in size on substrings and you find that you already have the current substring with the current continuation, you can stop.

Assuming that you have many words with the same letters, this will save some on space and inserts, at the cost of making actually generating the list slower.  Worst case is still `O(n*n)` for an `n` letter string though.

To delete you can follow a similar procedure, stopping deletes at any substring that has other substrings coming into it.